# SELECT multiple queries with multiple where clause

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, select

I have two select queries I want to combine for faster performance. I'm a bit confused as I'm not sure if I could use a `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` or something else to make it faster.

Here are the two queries I want to combine:

Query 1:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1
```

Then, if that row exists from query 1, then run query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = :id_from_query_1
```

thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: You have to further explain your situation; do your tables have any relationships, you have to clarify that and as well clearly state if what you have done does not work already or if it does only that you want to optimise the performance

Comment: Is `email` in `users` table UNIQUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a [join query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) you can specify what column to join on. In this case it would be:

```
select users.id, settings.*
from users
join settings on users.id = settings.id
```

You could also use a double `from` clause which I think results in the same speed background wise that would look like:

```
select users.id, settings.*
from users, settings
where users.id = settings.id
```

If proper indexes are set a join *should* be faster than 2 selects. Ofcourse there are many factors when it comes to speed like load, network, what is cached and what isn't etc.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, join should work.
Perhaps something like this:

```
select u.id, s.* from users as u join settings as s on u.id = s.id where email = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the 1st subquery will return 1 row (or none):

```
SELECT * FROM settings 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: This should return exactly what OP gets with two queries. And since we don't know, if `email` is UNIQUE - This is the only accurate answer yet. Though it looks suspicious that `settings.id` is referencing `users.id`. But that is OP's problem.

Comment: *Though it looks suspicious that settings.id is referencing users.id* correct! Maybe a typo? Should be something like user_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.* from settings s left join users u
ON u.id = s.id
Where email = :email
LIMIT 1;
```

This will return all the columns from Settings table with that particular ID which has the corresponding "email".

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM users u
WHERE email = :email 
LEFT JOIN settings s 
ON u.id = s.id
LIMIT 1
```

Here's the left join query for you.